# How to make stretchable circular region around pin like Reminder App

Tags: ios, objective-c, mkmapview

I tried following code to make circle:

```
MKCircle *circle = [MKCircle 
circleWithCenterCoordinate:userLocation.coordinate radius:1000];
[map addOverlay:circle];
```

Then in Map View's delegate:

```
- (MKOverlayView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)map viewForOverlay:(id <MKOverlay>)overlay
{
    MKCircleView *circleView = [[MKCircleView alloc] initWithOverlay:overlay];
    circleView.strokeColor = [UIColor redColor];
    circleView.fillColor = [[UIColor redColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.4];
    return circleView;
}
```

It adds a circle around the pin, but how to make the circle stretchable like Reminder App's Location Reminder feature?

[image]

Comment: hey, Were you able to do it ?

Comment: :-) Nope, I have stopped working on the app, but will definitely implement it someday. And if you it, by chance, do let me know. ;-)

Answer (score -2):

Look what I found:

https://github.com/d0ping/DBMapSelectorViewController

You can set up a lot of things like Radius of the circle, Background and Stroke color and even the Radius text.

Comment: Please improve this answer or it gets into trouble

Comment: Please check out [Take a tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [Your answer is in another castle: When is an answer not an answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370)